# Serializing TreeModel using jackson

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson

I have the following model:

```
public class CategoryModel {

    public String id;
    public String name;
    public String imageUrl;
    public CategoryModel parent;
    public List<CategoryModel> childrens = new ArrayList<CategoryModel>();
}
```

I am using Spring MVc + jackson to return Json.

My action build the following model and after the execution, i get stackoverflow exception.

```
List<CategoryModel> allCategories = new ArrayList<CategoryModel>(); 

CategoryModel model = new CategoryModel();
model.id = "1";
model.name = "category 1";

CategoryModel model1 = new CategoryModel();
model.id = "2";
model.name = "category 1.1";


model.childrens.add(model1);
model1.parent = model;

allCategories.add(model);
```

Any idea what's my problem ?

this is the log file (part of it):

> at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.StdContainerSerializers$IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(StdContainerSerializers.java:122)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.StdContainerSerializers$IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(StdContainerSerializers.java:71)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:86)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.StdContainerSerializers$IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(StdContainerSerializers.java:122)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.StdContainerSerializers$IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(StdContainerSerializers.java:71)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:86)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.StdContainerSerializers$IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(StdContainerSerializers.java:122)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.StdContainerSerializers$IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(StdContainerSerializers.java:71)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:86)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.StdContainerSerializers$IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(StdContainerSerializers.java:122)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.StdContainerSerializers$IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(StdContainerSerializers.java:71)
>   Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: Where does the exception occur?

Comment: your `CategoryModel` is overflooding with all the `CategoryModel` you're using everywhere. Using an instance of a class, within itself, and also having an ArrayList of itself is a disaster for memory.

Comment: how do you suggest to model this structure ?

Comment: it happens after execution of spring mvc action

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As *drorb* mentioned the cyclic reference is the problem. But instead of using the @JsonIgnore annotation you should use [@JsonBackReference](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/) to indicate the cyclic reference. With this annotation Jackson is able to map to the correct parent when deserializing.

Answer (score 0):

You have a cyclic reference in your model between model and model1 (parent/child) which is not automatically handled by jackson. 
You can go around this issue by  marking one of references to be ignored using the [@JsonIgnore](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.0.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnore.html) annotation.
You can find more information in this [article](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/02/entry_443.html)

Answer (score 0):

keeping long story short, I have done using above suggestions as below

```
Summary.java
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "summary")
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Section> issueSections;

Section.java
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonBackReference
@JoinColumn(name = "SUMMARY_ID", updatable = false)
private Summary summary;
```

this solved my issue.